# How to configure my Modbus rtu 3.5 character delay and 1.5 character delay using MPLAB mcc

Tags: timer, pic, modbus, mplab

I'm using PIC16f series microcontroller for my application. For that, how to configure 3.5 character time and 1.5 character time for MODBUS-RTU in MPLAB code configurator.

Comment: Hello, your question is too vague I'm afraid. Are you writing your own implementation or using a library? The obvious answer to your question is: use a timer. Maybe if you post your code somebody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the timer0 so that it interrupts every 1.5 character/2, for example if your 1 character time is 1 millisecond then 1.5 character time is 1.5 ms. So configure the timer0 so that it interrupts every 750 microseconds. Use two varibles, say timeFor15Char is for 1.5 character time and timeFor35Char is for 3.5 character time. Increment these variables in the timer interrupt. By the time timeFor15Char == 2 set a flag, let's call that flag15Char and then process it in your main loop. Same logic applies to timeFor35Char, you increment it in the timer0 interrupt service, check it if it reaches to 5 (3.5 char time is 3500 and 3500/750 = 4.6, round it up to 5), if it is so, then set a flag called flag35Char then process it in your main loop. One thing to note, don't forget to reset the flags after processing their related actions.